# How to use a sensor switch in combination with a manual On/OFF switch?

Tags: motion-sensor

I want to create following simple scenario.

I want to use a motion sensor light switch at the entrance of the room. It will be connected with a strip light in the room. So that when someone enters the room, the strip light switch On. Once in the room with strip lights turned ON through sensor switch, I want to switch of the sensor sensor lights from a manual switch and also stop the sensor, switching the Strip light ON , back again until, I allow it from the switch.
Actually, I want the motion sensor to work daily early morning to switch strip lights on, when first person (Receptionist) enters the room/building, so that strip lights will be on and after that this person will be able to manually switch OFF the lights and at the same time, the motion sensor will not switch them ON for next entries until next day. I.e. the receptionist will manually switch on the sensor functionality while leaving the office that day so that next morning when he/she arrives, the motion sensor works and switch ON the strip lights for one time and then he/she will be able to manually switch that OFF.
Kindly can someone please help on this with some circuit diagram for combination of Motion sensor and switch.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not want it to work during office hours, then it should be a simple wall switch to motion sensor circuit, same as a plain switch to light circuit.  The problem is it depends on a person to turn it on at the end of the day when they are tired and want to go home.  Some motion sensors have a light(daylight) sensor built in, so they don't work in daylight.

Comment: Actually, once in the morning lights are turned on and the first person entering the office find its way to the switch board, after that he should be able to switch off  those same lights that were switched ON with that motion sensor. A sort of 2 way switch but at the same time, the motion sensor should be de-active since next morning